# DUDA Para validar formulario con jQuery antes de "Comprobar Datos"

Tags: jquery, ajax, formularios, validación

Estoy viendo como puedo hacer una validación de un formulario con jQuery.

El formulario puede ser de "4 tipos" con lo que según la opción que al principio elijas:

- "Querría añadir un atributo required a los campos necesarios, claro que variará depende que opción elija el usuario al principio."

El required, lo añado de esta forma

> ```
> $(function(){
>        $("#idcampo").prop('required',true);
> });
> ```

Cuando el cliente rellena todo, puede pulsar un botón en que dice: "Comprobar Datos"

- Aquí es donde querría validar, antes de mostrar un modal con un resumen antes de enviar, de tal forma que si todos los "required" están rellenados, entonces si muestra el modal con el resumen.
- Si los campos required, no están completos, marcarlos en rojo, esto no me supone problema, ya que añadiría alguna class.

Creo que me he explicado correctamente, si alguien considera que no entiende mi duda, hacérmelo saber para intentar explicarlo mejor.

PD: El modal, lo tengo habilitado en jQuery, simplemente, .show()

Gracias de ante mano a la comunidad.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacer una Validacioin mediante Jquery, dependiendo donde, puede ser inseguro, recomiendo que valides en PHP, si sabes que el uso de tu formulario es de uso "exclusivo" para ciertas personas, continuo, en lugar de que el boton sea validar datos se puede llamar **Enviar** haces en el mismo un `onclick="enviar_fomulario();"` alli puedes validar los el formulario llamando dentro de esa funcion a otra funcion que sea `function validar_datos(<campos que quieras validad>)` la cosa mas o menos seria asi.

```
function enviar_formulario(){
  //puedes primero comprobar si los valores de los campos se recogen con un console.log()
  var campos = {$('#id_campo1').val(), $('#id_campo2').val()...}

  if(validar_datos(campos) == true){
    document.forms.<nombre_del_formulario>.submit();
  }else{
    //haces un alert o lo que sea
  }
}

function validar_datos(campos){
  for(var i in campos){
    if(campos[i] == ""){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

no sé si con esto te claro la pregunta, pero más o menos seria asi lo que pides seguramente tengas que cambiar alguna cosa pero bueno,

Un Saludo

Comment: Me gusta la opción de onclick, también lo veo mejor, y no se me había ocurrido, pero no entiendo porque metes un for dentro de la funcion validar_datos, el array, me imagino que es para recorrer todos los campos.

Comment: @JavierAvilaFernandez meto un for por que suponiendo que tengo 6 campos por validar, no le voy a pasar campo por campo a la funcion, los campos los meto en el array y si alguno de ellos es nulo devuelves false y haces lo que sea para decirle que lo rellene y asi con todos, si no cumplen algun requisito. el for en si es como para que sea un tanto "automatica" la tarea de validar, no sé si me he explicado bien jeje y si es asi dalie like a mi respuesta jaja un saludo

Comment: Genial, voy a utilizar este método! Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Dale like también a mi pregunta :D

Comment: De nada, y esto está hecho jaja